# How to print multiple copies of a document with lpr and keep the page order

Tags: lpr

`lpr -# 2 1-2.pdf` mixes the document's page order.

The first page is printed two times, then page two is printed two times.

Whereas this hacky loop keeps the page order

```bash
for i in {1..2}
do lpr 1-2.pdf
done
```

Is this really by design?

---

Arch Linux LTS

Comment: There are several different implementations of `lpr`. What OS or Linux/BSD distribution/version are you running?

Comment: Have you looking at `man lpr` to see if there is an option that enables _collate_ mode?

Comment: @ChrisDavies grepping `man lpr` shows no results

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Verbatim from https://www.cups.org/doc/options.html:

> Copies are normally not collated for you. Use the -o collate=true option to get collated copies:
>
> ```
> lp -n num-copies -o collate=true filename
> lpr -#num-copies -o collate=true filename
> ```

Comment: I don't see this option in `man`nor `--help`

Comment: The collation is done by the backend, so all that `lp` or `lpr` does is set a flag in the spool queue saying how many copies to do. `-o ...` is just a generic way for these 2 commands to pass on options to the backend or intermediate programs. All the possible options cannot be listed, as they are invented by the backend, eg "papertray=bottom". Use `lpoptions` to list the options for the printer, but some options will be done by cups itself, hence the need to read the cups documentation too.